# How do I create a Vim keybind that involves numbers (0-9)?

Tags: vim

I want to create a keybind for setting the fold level to a specific number. The ex command is:

```
:set foldlevel=n
```

Where `n` is the fold level. I want to bind `<leader>z` plus a number to set the fold level. My goal is this invocation (assuming my leader key is `\`):

```
\z3
```

And it should in turn invoke this command:

```
:set foldlevel=3
```

Is it possible to involve numbers in keybinds like this? If so, how is it done?

Comment: Isn't `zf<N>j` enogh for you? Example: `zf5j`

Comment: @radubogdan: My question isn't about creating folds. My question is about making a keybind for setting the `foldlevel` setting to a variable number.

Comment: I know, but is weird to setup a variable and "call" fold when you can call it directly with any number. If you understand what I mean. I will think at your problem though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way is the other way around, with `[count]` coming first. This makes is easy to handle numbers larger than single-digit (though it's probably not so important for foldlevels). You can use the `v:count` special variable, as in:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <Leader>z :<C-u>let &foldlevel = v:count<CR>
```

The `<C-u>` is needed to remove the automatically inserted range. I use `:let` for the option assignment, though `:execute` would have worked, too.

Comment: Interestingly, if I don't provide a count, `v:count` evaluates to 0, which makes the command basically do the same as `zM`. Very cool!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
for key in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  exe "nmap <silent> <leader>" . key . " " . ":set foldlevel=" . key . "<cr>"
endfor
```

You need to use to use the `execute` command if you want to build up dynamic mappings. The dot stands for string concatenation, in case you're not familiar with vimscript.

Comment: That's not what I had in mind, but it works. Nice! Out of curiosity, how would you solve this if you wanted the invocation `3\z`? Would that be more elegant?

Comment: I guess @Ingo answered that, it's just a matter of personal taste in this case. In other scenarios putting the count first gives you more flexibility.